# Develop a module that adds a new content type with custom fields

Tags: nodes, entities

How do I start to develop a Drupal 7 module that adds a new content type with some custom fields, so it generates all the output I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although its possible to do programatically, your easiest bet would be to use [features](http://drupal.org/project/features).

This is how you would do it:

1. Manually create your content type
2. Manually add fields
3. Create a new feature and export the content type (and its fields)
4. Done!

Now if you install this feature is a fresh Drupal installation that content type and fields will be automatically added.

Comment: Well I need to develop this as a normal module. So can I later add more code in the files and "upgrade" this module and it works like a totally normal module?   Is it better to rely on features or is it better to write a module from scratch that makes all this and creates the content ype, adds the fields ...  and later does some database querys, file conversion ...?

Comment: You can always update your content type, re-create the feature and existing installations will be updated. And if you want to add something special, you can always implement a second module which does that using the various hook_node_* hooks.

Comment: Well I will give it a try.

Comment: You can just add your code to the .module file created by features, for Drupal this is just a regular module.