# Adding an address to a node's address field programmatically

Tags: 7, entities

I am presenting a form to receive an address.  I want to take the data and add it to a node that has an address field (from the address field module).

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provided a code example using entity_metadata_wrapper() in [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1298978#comment-7368632). As soon as I finish cleaning up the issue queue, I'll make a regular documentation page out of that. You can follow [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1267292) to see when the documentation page gets published.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PHP snippet that can be used to set an [address field](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) on a node.

## PHP

```
$lang = $node->language;
$node->field_address[$lang][0] = array(
  "country" => "US",
  "thoroughfare" => "123 Fake Street",
  "premise" => "",
  "locality" => "Beverly Hills",
  "administrative_area" => "CA",
  "postal_code" => "90210"
);
```

And for reference, here's the JSON that can be used with the [Services](https://drupal.org/project/services) module.

## JSON via Services Module

```
{
  "nid":123,
  "field_address":{"und":[{
    "country":"US",
    "thoroughfare":"123 Fake Street",
    "premise":"",
    "locality":"Beverly Hills",
    "administrative_area":"CA",
    "postal_code":"90210"
  }]}
}
```

This example works for the US only, see [addressfield_get_address_format()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/addressfield/tree/addressfield.address_formats.inc) for the components that are required for your desired country(ies).

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 8 the data insert will work only if 'country' is changed to 'country_code' and 'thoroughfare' is changed to 'address_line1'. Hence the code will be as follows

```
$lang = $node->language;
$node->field_address[$lang][0] = array(
  "country_code" => "US",
  "address_line1" => "123 Fake Street",
  "locality" => "Beverly Hills",
  "administrative_area" => "CA",
  "postal_code" => "90210"
);
```